# Debugger stopping on ASIHTTPRequest's scheduleReadStream with no error

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

The debugger pauses within ASIHTTPRequest's scheduleReadStream method, but produces no errors.

More specifically, it's stopping on this line:

```
[[self readStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:[self runLoopMode]];
```

No matter how many times I hit play, it doesn't move off this line or report any errors in the console. I did notice that the main thread advances through some of its operations when I hit play, however.

The way I have things setup, I have a downloader that's working on a background thread (so it can do parsing and image manipulation when it receives it from the completed requests). This downloader object is using an `ASINetworkQueue` to schedule the requests. I'm wondering if maybe this is causing a deadlock.

Here's the snippet of code that adds the requests to the queue after parsing some data from a request that just finished (not part of the queue).

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        if ([parser parse]) {
            //Add pending operations
            for (NSNumber * key in self.currentRequests.keyEnumerator) {
                //Unrelated code getting the request from a dictionary
                [self.networkQueue addOperation:request];
            }
            [self.networkQueue go];
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I'm also doing unrelated requests asynchronously throughout the code, which could be going on at the same time as this queue is being filled/told to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out there was an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` but it wasn't showing up when running on the iPhone. When running on the simulator it actually showed up properly. This bad access was due to the fact that I didn't use the `initWithURL` method, instead setting the URL (since when creating the object I didn't have the URL available yet). I call `initWithURL` now once the URL is ready and everything is good.